# Probability of Random Variables given their Density

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose X and Y are independent random variables with densities:

Fx(x) = 4x³   for 0 < x < 1 (equals 0 otherwise)

Fy(y) = y/2 for 0 < y < 2 (equals 0 otherwise)

Calculate P(Y>4X)

I know to start that P(Y > 4X) = P(Y - 4X > 0) so I need to define some new random variable Z = Y - 4X... but I'm not too sure where to go from here. Could someone help me out please? Any help would be great!

Comment: Do I need to work out the variance and mean for these densities or is there a way of doing it otherwise?

Comment: You don't need to work out variance or mean. The idea is to integrate over the common distribution of $X$ and $Y$ which is just the product distribution

Comment: We have $$\mathbb P(4X<Y)=\int_0^2 \mathrm dy\left(\frac y2\cdot\int_0^{\frac{y}4} 4x^3\mathrm dx\right)$$ Can you see why and can you finish it from there?

Comment: You can use the continuous version of the law of total probability. Then you have something like $$P(Y>4X) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(y>4X|Y=y)f_Y(y)\;dy$$ $$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X<\tfrac y4)f_Y(y)\;dy$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the random variables are independent you can condition on the law of $X$ to obtain
$${\bf P}(Y \geq 4X) = \int_0^1{\bf P}(Y \geq 4x)F_X(x)dx = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^2 1_{\{y \geq 4x\}}F_Y(y)dy\right)F_X(x)dx,$$
which can be computed using standard methods. ($1_{A}$ is the indicator function of the set $A$.)

Comment: It is $y\geq 4x$ not $x\geq 4y$

Comment: Thanks, I mixed up the variables.

Comment: @GautamShenoy What kantadou did is correct; the confusion comes from the fact that OP named their densities capital $F$

Comment: I just realized that. Thats why i deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(Y>4X)=\int_0^1 P(Y>4x|X=x)f_X(x)dx=\int_0^1 P(Y>4x)f_X(x)dx=\int_0^1 \left(\int_{4x}^2 f_Y(y)dy \right)f_X(x)dx$$
where the second inequality follows from the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I am sure you can calculate the rest.

Comment: When I calculate the rest a get a probability greater than 1...